# Efficiently loop through structs in Julia

Tags: julia

I have a simple question. I have defined a struct, and I need to inititate a lot (in the order of millions) of them and loop over them.

I am initiating one at a time and going through the loop as follows:

```
using Distributions

mutable struct help_me{Z<:Bool}
    can_you_help_me::Z
    millions_of_thanks::Z
end

for i in 1:max_iter
    tmp_help = help_me(rand(Bernoulli(0.5),1)[1],rand(Bernoulli(0.99),1)[1])
    # many follow-up processes 
end
```

The memory allocation scales up in **max_iter**. For my purpose, I do not need to save each struct. Is there a way to "re-use" the memory allocation used by the struct?

Comment: Question 1: why are you doing `Z<:Bool`? `Bool` is already a concrete type?
Question 2: any reason `help_me` needs to be `mutable`? immutable structs are often cheaper. also passing a `rng` explicitly into `rand` can give you an easy 2x speedup. (due to multithreading safety reasons)

Comment: Hi Osca, thanks you for questions.

1. Did not know. Thanks.
2. It might not be actually. Thanks. I am still working out processes that each agent needs to go through.
3. Did not know. Thanks.

Any solution to the memory allocation problem?

Comment: I think making the struct not `mutable` would fix this. immutable objects can be stack allocated (in most cases), so creating and destroying them should end up being basically free.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your main problem lies here:

```
rand(Bernoulli(0.5),1)[1], rand(Bernoulli(0.99),1)[1]
```

You are creating a length-1 array and then reading the first element from that array. This allocates unnecessary memory and takes time. Don't create an array here. Instead, write

```
rand(Bernoulli(0.5)), rand(Bernoulli(0.99))
```

This will just create random scalar numbers, no array.

Compare timings here:

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> @btime rand(Bernoulli(0.5),1)[1]
  36.290 ns (1 allocation: 96 bytes)
false

julia> @btime rand(Bernoulli(0.5))
  6.708 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
false
```

6 times as fast, and no memory allocation.

This seems to be a general issue. Very often I see people writing `rand(1)[1]`, when they should be using just `rand()`.

Also, consider whether you actually need to make the struct `mutable`, as others have mentioned.

Comment: Thanks. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If the structure is not needed anymore (i.e. not referenced anywhere outside the current loop iteration), the Garbage Collector will free up its memory automatically if required.

Otherwise, I agree with the suggestions of Oscar Smith: memory allocation and garbage collection take time, avoid it for performance reasons if possible.